# Mac OS Quit Application menu label same as python script name

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, py2app, pyobjc

When I run my wxPython app in Mac OS X, the "Quit" menu item under the Application menu has the label "Quit Myapp", where `myapp.py` is the name of the main python script. If I rename it to, for example, `coolapp.py`, the label on the menu item becomes "Quit Coolapp".

Even when I package the application using py2app, although the Application menu changes from 'Python' to the name specified in my `setup.py`, the Quit menu item remains the same.

How can I change this menu item to use a different application name? Is there any way to use the pyobjc bridge with wxPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, PyObjC is not required, and this can be done from wxPython only.

The function to call is `SetAppName(name)`, but this *must be done from the* `OnInit(self):` *method*. Previously I was calling this function after the App instance had been created, and it did nothing.

Your code should look like this:

```
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        # Set application name before anything else
        self.SetAppName("My App Name")
        mainframe = MyMainFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(mainframe)
        mainframe.Show()
        return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp = MyApp()
    myapp.MainLoop()
```